# C - simultaneous receiving and handling data from unix sockets

Tags: c, sockets, fork

I have a C program which communicates with PHP through Unix Sockets. The procedure is as follows: PHP accepts a file upload by the user, then sends a "signal" to C which then dispatches another process (fork) to unzip the file (I know this could be handled by PHP alone, this is just an example; the whole problem is more complex).

The problem is that I don't want to have more than say 4 processes running at the same time. I think this could be solved like this: C, when it gets a new "task" from PHP dumps it on a queue and handles them one-by-one (assuring that there are no more than 4 running) while still listening on the socket.

I'm unsure how to achieve this though, as I cannot do that in the same process (or can I)? I have thought I could have another child process for managing the queue which would be accessible by the parent with the use of shared memory, but that seems overly complicated. Is there any other way around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a separate process for each task handler, then you might consider having five separate processes. The first one is the listener, and handles new incoming tasks, and places it into a queue. Each task handler initially sends a request for work, and also when it is finished processing a task. When the listener receives this request, it delivers the next task on the queue to the task handler, or it places the task handler on a handler queue if the task queue is empty. When the task queue transitions from empty to non-empty, it checks if there is a ready task handler in the handler queue. If so, it takes that task handler out of the queue, and delivers the task from the task queue to the task handler.

The PHP process would put tasks to the listener, while the task handlers would get tasks from the listener. The listener simply waits for put or get requests, and processes them. You can think of the listener as a simple web server, but each of the socket connections to the PHP process and to each task handler can be persistent.

Since the number of sockets is small and persistent, any of the multiplexing calls could work (`select`, `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue`, or whatever is best and or available for your system), but it may be easiest to use a separate thread to handle each socket synchronously. The ready task handler queue would then be a semaphore or a condition variable on the task queue. The thread that handles puts from the PHP process would place tasks on the task queue, and up the semaphore. Each thread that handles ready tasks would down the semaphore, then take a task off the task queue. The task queue itself may itself need mutual exclusive protection depending on how it is implemented.

Comment: That seems interesing, I haven't thought of having those separate processes. I'll give it a try tomorrow and I'll see what I get.

Comment: OK, I have implemented a basic version with the use of fork() and 5 persistent socket connections. Maybe I'll try with threads later. Either way, thank you, you've been very helpful.